# R Predict function using a character variable as the model name

Tags: r, predict

I have my model name as a variable:

```
model <- paste0("GBM_",risk_code,"_",risk_category, sep = "")
```

And want to predict based on this name:

```
pred1 <- predict(model, n.trees = model$n.trees, data)
```

I want to run a loop to predict for multiple different model names.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `pred1 <- predict(get(model), n.trees = model$n.trees, data)` ?

Comment: That's the answer, thank you